# zip, sorted and pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, zip

I have a pandas data frame with column values as follows :

```
names = wine_df.columns
names
Index([u'fixed acidity', u'volatile acidity', u'citric acid', u'residual sugar', u'chlorides', u'free sulfur dioxide', u'total sulfur dioxide', u'density', u'pH', u'sulphates', u'alcohol'], dtype='object')
```

I have a numpy array named imp with following values:

```
array([ 0.07640909,  0.11346059,  0.09160943,  0.06674312,  0.07203855,
        0.06306923,  0.08272078,  0.0839144 ,  0.05996705,  0.11833288,
        0.17173489])
```

I was working on a project and I came across this piece of code shown below:

```
zip(*sorted(zip(imp, names)))
```

I couldn't understand why are they using *sorted inside the zip function?? Also why are they using zip function twice??

Comment: they are  transposing the sorted zipped list, `zip(imp, names)` zip together, then sort `sorted(zip(imp, names))` finally transpose `zip(*sorted(zip(imp, names)))`

Comment: You could have printed each statement in expanded form to see what is happening

Comment: @PadraicCunningham transposing?? I couldnt understand that.

Comment: rows become columns and columns become rows, try `x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) print x.T`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - No, I know the meaning of transpose. but how does zip of zip perform a transpose, thats where I am confused with. in numpy you can transpose an array using .T command. but zip function is used to create pairs right?? but how does it perform a transpose here??

Comment: that is what the `*` is doing. How could you zip a  single list which is exactly what you have calling sorted on the zipped lists?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Now I got where I am confused with, how is zip(*zipped list) and zip(zipped list) different?. I understood what exactly does ** and * perform in python ,https://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/. but in this context I am slightly confused.

Comment: When used with zip on a single iterable it transposes it. It is all about the context in which you use it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Ok then I will remember this as a  technique for transposing using zip. I will add this to my anki card.

Comment: one thing to be aware of is if you start out with numpy arrays you won't end up with a numpy array, you will have a python list so you may want to use numpy.transpose

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sure I will keep this point in mind. huh!! I got a negative point for this question. no probs I have got a good understand of this concept. thanks for the last tip. I was  experimenting with numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to see what his is doing is with a simple example:

```
In [11]: a = np.array([2, 1, 3])

In [12]: a = np.array([2, 1, 2, 3])

In [13]: b = np.array(['b', 'b', 'a', 'c'])

In [14]: sorted(zip(a, b))
Out[14]: [(1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

In [15]: zip(*sorted(zip(a, b)))
Out[15]: [(1, 2, 2, 3), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'c')]
```

*It sorts both lists/arrays with respect to values in the first (followed by values in the second).*

A more "numpy" way to do this would be to use argsort (which will be much more performant for larger arrays):

```
In [21]: s = np.argsort(a)

In [22]: a[s], b[s]
Out[22]:
(array([1, 2, 2, 3]), array(['b', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
       dtype='|S1'))
```

*Note: gives a slightly different result, as it doesn't deal with draws in a.*

Comment: Got it. Crystal clear explanation. argsort even gives me the indices of alphabets, for eg: np.argsort(b). How does it operate on alphabets??

Comment: @user3796494 unicode is orderable, you will have issues trying to unorderable objects (e.g. in python3 you can't compare integers and strings/letters)